# Django Display image & image file name in a template

Tags: python, django, image

I am trying to display multiple images (20 - 30) with the image file also being displayed.

I have the images displayed but I am not sure how to get the image file name to display beside it / underneath it.

I am new to Django.

Here's what I have done so far:

**template.html**

```
   <div class="container-fluid my-container">
    {% filter_images_normal 6 as images %}

    <div class="row no-pad display-flex  my-row">
        {% for image in images %}
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col my-col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 my-col">
                <input class="img-thumbnail" type="image" id="image" alt="Image" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{ image }}">
              <p>Image name file here</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**filter_images.py** (template tag)

```
@register.simple_tag
def filter_images_normal(count=3):
    valid_extensions = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')
    rand_dir = '/static/app_filter/images/normal/'
    path = '/app_filter/static/app_filter/images/normal/'

    files = [f for f in os.listdir(settings.BASE_DIR + path)
             if f[f.rfind("."):] in valid_extensions]

    # print(random.sample(files, count))
    print(rand_dir)
    return [rand_dir + filename for filename in random.sample(files, count)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass image as list of dict from template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def filter_images_normal(count=3):
    valid_extensions = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')
    rand_dir = '/static/app_filter/images/normal/'
    path = '/app_filter/static/app_filter/images/normal/'

    files = [f for f in os.listdir(settings.BASE_DIR + path)
             if f[f.rfind("."):] in valid_extensions]

    # print(random.sample(files, count))
    print(rand_dir)
    return [{'name':filename, 'url':rand_dir + filename} for filename in random.sample(files, count)]
```

in template call `{{image.url}}` and `{{image.name}}`

```
<div class="row no-pad display-flex  my-row">
    {% for image in images %}
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col my-col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 my-col">
            <input class="img-thumbnail" type="image" id="image" alt="Image" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{image.url}}">
          <p>{{ image.name }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I just realized that it doesn't actually return any images when I update the code. The  images that are output are from this line: `random.sample(files, count)`. Which when printed also contains the name of the image file. Is there a way that I could reference random.sample(files, count) in the template?

Comment: @Dom then you will need to return `random.sample(files,count)` from the template tag along with the list. why do you want `random.sample(files,count)`

Comment: When I print `rand_dir + filename` I get the list of images like so `['image1.jpg', ..]` . In the template those images are outputted. So If I could also output the name of the image, that would solve the problem which is why I want `random.sample(files, count)`. But I'm unsure on how to do this.

Comment: @Dom i didn't get you. `rand_dir + filename` will print like `/static/app_filter/images/normal/dom.jpg`. i think you problem is the image not displayed in the template?. i think change `rand_dir` to ` 'app_filter/images/normal/'` will solve the problem